# Avoid recreating the GET logic in the POST part of a view

Tags: python, django, django-views

How can I avoid duplicating the logic code from the `GET` block in the view below?

The logic is view-specific enough that I don't feel it makes sense to put a helper function in a separate utils.py.

```
'''
show_stuff view shows different stuff depending on how many other 
POST requests have been submitted to view and saved to the DB.
All the users access the same URL randomly, so I don't believe it's possible to
split things up like "view_for_template1", "view_for_template2" in urls.py
'''
def show_stuff(request, url_dispatch_var1, url_dispatch_var2=None):
    if request.method == "GET":
        #30 lines of logic determining which Template and Context to return
    if request.method =="POST":
        #10 lines of logic determining which Form type to save
        #then, the same 30 lines of logic as the GET block to determine 
        #which Template and Context to return
```

Comment: This is a bit too general to answer. But you don't need to put your extracted function in a separate utils module; it can just go in the same place as the views.

Comment: Without any information about how this view is called or what determines anything its impossible to tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually do something like the following:

```
def show_stuff(request, url_dispatch_var1, url_dispatch_var2=None):
    if request.method =="POST":
        #10 lines of logic determining which Form type to save
        # redirect if form is valid
    else:
        # this is a GET request
        form = MyForm() # unbound form for get request 
    # 30 lines of logic to determine which Template and Context to return
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Note that after a successful post request, the usual approach is to redirect to prevent duplicate submissions.

This *might* be a case where class based views are useful. You could subclass `FormView`, then override `get_context_data`, `get_template_names` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering if I could avoid the redirect to avoid hitting the webserver "twice" per form submission, but I guess keeping the code clean is more important.

Comment: You don't have to redirect, but it's recommended. Hitting the server twice per submission probably won't cause performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of returning body for POST request you could redirect user to your GET view ?

Comment: This uselessly adds a lot of overhead. Rather than executing 30 lines, you are returning a response to the client, asking him to do another request, which you will have to respond.

Comment: Actually I thought about internally doing redirect, so the user doesn't have to do anything.

Comment: What do you mean "internally"?

Comment: From Django docs:

Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
user hits the Back button.

Comment: This is not internal. Fair enough reason though.